# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -101, don't know how to change query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an application where I want to run SQL queries that I store in an orm.xml file. Now I'm getting an No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -101 exception. I think I know that it's because of the timestamp in my query, but I don't know how to change it.. I've read some things that you could use .addScalar(), but I can't do that in the repository.. I think I will have to change the query, but I don't know how. Maybe I'm totally wrong, but hopefully someone can help.

This is the code:

```
    @Entity
public class Tables {
    @javax.persistence.Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "DATE")
    private String date;
    @Column(name = "BRIDGEID")
    private String bridgeID;
    @Column(name = "REQUESTTYPE")
    private String requestType;
    @Column(name = "REQUESTSPECIFICATION")
    private String requestSpecification;
    @Column(name = "FAULTDESCRIPTION")
    private String faultDescription;
    @Column(name = "SOURCESYSTEM")
    private String sourceSystem;
    @Column(name = "EVENTID")
    private String eventID;
    @Column(name = "MESSAGEID")
    private String messageID;
    @Column(name = "RELATESTO")
    private String relatesTo;
    @Column(name = "SYSTIMESTAMP")
    private String sysTimeStamp;
```

This the repository:

```
public interface TablesRepository extends JpaRepository<Tables, Long> {
    List<Tables> getTest();
```

The query:

```
select to_char(starttimestamp, 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss DY') as "DATE",
            bint.bridgeid,
            requestType,
            RequestSpecification,
            bfa.faultdescription,
            case
            when requestMessage is not null then
            dbms_lob.substr(substr(bMes.requestMessage,
            INSTR(bMes.requestMessage, 'SourceSystem', 1) +
            length('SourceSystem') + 1,
            (INSTR(bMes.requestMessage,
            'SourceSystem',
            1,
            2) - INSTR(bMes.requestMessage,
            'SourceSystem',
            1) -
            length('SourceSystem') - 3)))
            end as sourceSystem,
            case
            when requestMessage is not null then
            dbms_lob.substr(substr(bMes.requestMessage,
            INSTR(bMes.requestMessage, 'EventId', 1) +
            length('EventId') + 1,
            (INSTR(bMes.requestMessage, 'EventId', 1, 2) -
            INSTR(bMes.requestMessage, 'EventId', 1) -
            length('EventId') - 3)))
            end as EventId,
            bint.MessageId,
            bint.relatesto,
            systimestamp
            from baseintegrationheaders bint
            left join baseMessages bMes
            on bMes.relatesto = bint.relatesto
            left join basefaults bfa
            on bfa.relatesto = bint.relatesto
            where 1 = 1
            and bint.applicationid in ('testApplication')
            and requestType not in ( 'WorkerRunning'
            , 'BridgeEnd'
            , 'BridgeStart'
            , 'WorkerEnd'
            , 'WorkerMQEnd'
            , 'WorkerMQStart'
            , 'WorkerProducerEnd'
            , 'WorkerProducerStart'
            , 'WorkerReaderEnd'
            , 'WorkerReaderStart'
            , 'WorkerStart'
            , 'WorkerStop'
            )
            and ((requestType = 'BridgeRequest' and faultindication = 'true') or
            (requestType <> 'BridgeRequest'))
            order by bint.MessageId, 1
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -101; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -101
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331) ~[spring-orm-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220) ~[spring-aop-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy129.getPayCnaBridge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ObjectHelper.invokeMethodSafe(ObjectHelper.java:384) ~[camel-support-3.20.5.jar!/:3.20.5]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:494) ~[camel-bean-3.20.5.jar!/:3.20.5]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:316) ~[camel-bean-3.20.5.jar!/:3.20.5]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:286) ~[camel-bean-3.20.5.jar!/:3.20.5]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.AbstractBeanProcessor.process(AbstractBeanProcessor.java:146) ~[camel-bean-3.20.5.jar!/:3.20.5]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:81) ~[camel-bean-3.20.5.jar!/:3.20.5]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:477) ~[camel-core-processor-3.20.5.jar!/:3.20.5]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:181) ~[camel-base-engine-3.20.5.jar!/:3.20.5]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59) ~[camel-base-engine-3.20.5.jar!/:3.20.5]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:165) ~[camel-core-processor-3.20.5.jar!/:3.20.5]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:392) ~[camel-base-engine-3.20.5.jar!/:3.20.5]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:210) ~[camel-timer-3.20.5.jar!/:3.20.5]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:76) ~[camel-timer-3.20.5.jar!/:3.20.5]
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:516) ~[na:na]
```